# How to return a pointer to a C++ object to python using boost if the class of that object is declared in another boost module?

Tags: python, c++, boost-python, python-c-api, python-extensions

Okay, maybe I'm not finding an answer because I'm not sure how to word it, but I have a class called Info and another class called Packet, both are compiled into Python extensions using boost, and I would like to return a pointer to an Info object from the Packet module.

info.cpp

```
#include "info.h"
Info::Info(int i_, int j_){
    this->i = i_;
    this->j = j_;
} 

Info::~Info(){
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Info)
{
    class_<Info>("Info", init<int, int>())
    .def_readwrite("i", &Info::i)
    .def_readwrite("j", &Info::j);
}
```

Packet.cpp:

```
Packet::Packet(int i_, int j_, PyObject* addr_, bool a_, bool b_){
    this->i = i_;
    this->j - j_;
    this->addr = addr_;
    this->a = a_;
    this->b = b_;
}
// some other functions

Info* Packet::test(){
    return new Info(1,2);
}
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Packet)
{
    class_<Packet>("Packet", init<int, int, PyObject*, bool, bool>())
        /*some other functions*/
        .def("test", &Packet::test, return_value_policy<reference_existing_object>());
}
```

testPacket.py:

```
from Packet import *
# this works correctly
p = Packet(1,2, None, False, False)
# this crashes
t = p.test()
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/lirui/testPacket.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(p.test())
TypeError: No Python class registered for C++ class Info
```

Is there any way I can return a pointer to an Info object?

Thanks

Comment: Don't you need to import `Info` too? It says right there it isn't registered... I don't know this technology well, though.

Comment: hey that worked, I thought all I needed was to import it in the .cpp and link them toghether in the makefile... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only imported `Packet`.

You also need to import `Info`.

Otherwise, as the error says, Python doesn't recognise it when `p.test()` attempts to use it (or, more specifically, to return a pointer to it, to assign to `t`).